# How to add X axis and Y axis labels on Raphael js charts

Tags: graph, raphael, graphael

I'm trying to use Raphael.js to do some nice graphing for data after which I realize there are several limitations to the js which I'm trying to solve.

Does anyone knows how to scale the y axis value dynamically as I've realized that once the values cross >500 , the graphing does not appear at all , only the axes appears with plots at the extreme edges in one line (i.e. over the limit).

Secondly is there a way to add legends or axis labels to the graphs ? Or must graph labels be coded separately as html ?

Thanks Lots !!! Its a great looking tool but it seems quite useless ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chart g.bar.js does not have an option to draw axes. If you look inside g.line.js, however, there is a block of code around lines 98-117 (currently) that draws axes:

```
    var allx = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], valuesx),
        ally = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], valuesy),
        xdim = chartinst.snapEnds(Math.min.apply(Math, allx), Math.max.apply(Math, allx), valuesx[0].length - 1),
        minx = xdim.from,
        maxx = xdim.to,
        ydim = chartinst.snapEnds(Math.min.apply(Math, ally), Math.max.apply(Math, ally), valuesy[0].length - 1),
        miny = ydim.from,
        maxy = ydim.to,
        kx = (width - gutter * 2) / ((maxx - minx) || 1),
        ky = (height - gutter * 2) / ((maxy - miny) || 1);

    var axis = paper.set();

    if (opts.axis) {
        var ax = (opts.axis + "").split(/[,\s]+/);
        +ax[0] && axis.push(chartinst.axis(x + gutter, y + gutter, width - 2 * gutter, minx, maxx, opts.axisxstep || Math.floor((width - 2 * gutter) / 20), 2, paper));
        +ax[1] && axis.push(chartinst.axis(x + width - gutter, y + height - gutter, height - 2 * gutter, miny, maxy, opts.axisystep || Math.floor((height - 2 * gutter) / 20), 3, paper));
        +ax[2] && axis.push(chartinst.axis(x + gutter, y + height - gutter, width - 2 * gutter, minx, maxx, opts.axisxstep || Math.floor((width - 2 * gutter) / 20), 0, paper));
        +ax[3] && axis.push(chartinst.axis(x + gutter, y + height - gutter, height - 2 * gutter, miny, maxy, opts.axisystep || Math.floor((height - 2 * gutter) / 20), 1, paper));
    }
```

This can effectively be copy and pasted into the function VBarchart in g.bar.js to give you axes options. A little adjustment to x and y positions will be required, and maxy should probably be set to opts.total to get the scaling right - yes, you will need to fart around with it a bit, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip stephband ! Had been puzzled by it or the lack of information and switched to using highcharts instead, works great too !

Comment: @stephband: Can you please elaborate the little adjustments.. I tried to copy it in the mentioned file. but not working.. Can u please help. Thank you

Comment: @stephband: or any demo please?

Comment: I haven't had to use Raphael since I wrote this answer two years ago, and I'd assume it's changed a great deal since then so the answer is out of date. Sorry.

Comment: @stephband there is still no axis support for bar charts in gRaphael after 2 long years xD